# DIVs change color by "click" with event handler

Tags: javascript, loops, events, for-loop, event-handling

I want to create an event where the DIVs are clicked and they change to a random color. I'm fairly confident that this is the general setup, but I'm just overlooking some small error(s)...

**HTML**

```
<style>
    .square {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var squareRef = document.getElementById("container");

for(var i = 0; i < squareRef.length; i++) {
    squareRef[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}

function changeColor(event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "randomColor()";
}


function randomColor() {
    var randomRed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randomGreen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randomBlue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    //create the string that is the ‘random color’
    var randomColor = "rgb("+randomRed+","+randomGreen+","+randomBlue+")";

    return randomColor;
}
```

Comment: `var squareRef = document.getElementById("container");` just returns the outermost `div` and not an array of `divs` inside it like you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r2vfa2s4/

Two things.

Change the first line to:

```
var squareRef = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
```

Remove quotes when you invoke randomColor(). I.e.:

```
event.target.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Made Mistakes on Two Lines

You Have to change color of particular div not the container div so please change this

```
var squareRef = document.getElementById("container");
```

To

var squareRef = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

AND

You are calling function in a wrong way:

Change this line

```
event.target.style.backgroundColor = "randomColor()";
```

To

```
event.target.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
```

Try This

```js
var squareRef = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

for(var i = 0; i < squareRef.length; i++) {
    squareRef[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}

function changeColor(event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}


function randomColor() {
    var randomRed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randomGreen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randomBlue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    //create the string that is the ‘random color’
    var randomColor = "rgb("+randomRed+","+randomGreen+","+randomBlue+")";

    return randomColor;
}
```

```css
.square {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the JavaScript, this works:

```
var ref = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("square"));

ref.forEach(function(v,k,a)
{
    v.onclick = function()
    {
        var clr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'hsla('+clr+',100%,50%,1)';
    };
});
```

By the way:
looping through a nodeList got from "getElementsByClassName", produces an error when trying to reference, as a nodeList contains non-elements as well.

The `[].slice.call` part takes care of that ;)